# Does c++ dereference assignment do a bitwise or "smart" assignment?

Tags: c++, copy, bit-manipulation, variable-assignment, dereference

I'm wondering if

```
*this = *that
```

will do a bitwise assignment of 'that' to 'this', or call the assignment operator for the class of 'this'.

Thanks!

Comment: No real reason for the compiler to override the normal behavior when you decide to use a pointer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It calls the assignment operator, like `this->operator=(*that);`.

Comment: So I'm writing a container class, with Cells of each object inputed. I'm writing the assignment operator - is it safe to do *thisObject = *thatObject? If it is a container of dynamically allocated objects, then the proper constructors for the thisobject Class will be called? What if 'thisObject' is not a pointer?

Comment: It might be better if your container's assignment operator copy-constructs copies of the objects of the original rather than assign them, since in general you wouldn't know who to assign them to. Basically, if you're re-writing `vector`, do it like `vector` does.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean - currently I'm deleting all Cells in the 'this' Stack (I'm writing a stack), resetting its variables, and looping through the 'that' Stack and adding them into the 'this' stack. I guess I'm also wondering how I could check if the type is a pointer - if so I would use the dereference assignment above to hopefully do a deep copy and push it to the stack. And if it's not, I need to find a way to not use dereference as to not cause an error